# Combinatorics Problem - Identical Balls

Tags: combinatorics

We have $5$ white balls and $7$ black balls. Assume white balls cannot be placed side by side.
In how many ways can we place all the balls in a line if white and black balls are identical?

Solution Attempt

We have $12$ objects of two different types.
We have $5$ objects of type one and $7$ objects of type two.

number of permutations = ${12}\choose{5}$ * ${7}\choose{7}$

Comment: I don't think you accounted for the "white balls cannot be placed side by side" condition.

Comment: Why do you call the expression the "number of permutations"? Or you write this only to add "context"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We place 7 black balls first, leaving 8 places to be filled by 5 white balls, -B-B-B-B-B-B-B-,  so the answer is $C_5^8$.

Comment: +1, somehow I missed this very straightforward approach

Answer (score 2):

Valid orderings can be built up by starting with "WBWBWBWBW" and positioning the remaining three black balls in the 6 "gaps" between (and outside of) the white balls.

The number of ways to place these three balls is the number of solutions to $3 = x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_6$ where $x_i$ are nonnegative integers. This can be computed using the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two) approach, which yields $\binom{6+3-1}{3} = \binom{8}{3}$.

---

Equivalently, you can build up valid orderings by arranging 5 white balls and 3 black balls without restrictions ($\binom{8}{5}$ ways), and then insert 4 additional black balls, one between each pair of white balls.